# Trigger a Google Analytics for Firebase function doesn't work

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to trigger a cloud function when an specific event happens, but it does not work.

I have marked the event as conversion event in the Events tab of the Firebase console Analytics pane.

When the event is triggered, I can see it in the Debug View tab of the Firebase console Analytics pane, but nothing happens in Firebase console Function pane.

Here I leave you my index.js file:
[image]

Comment: Has it been at least 2 hours since you first deployed your function and made the event a conversion event?  [The documentation says:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events) _There is currently a delay of up to two hours between the first deployment of an Analytics function and the time when it starts to receive events. Once the function is receiving events, you can deploy updates to its code with no delay. There is also a similar delay any time you change the type of Analytics event for a function. This delay is only for the duration of Beta_

Comment: Yes, it has been at least 1 week since I have deployed the function and made the event as a conversion event.

Comment: The current version of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events) doesn't mention anything about the delay. But the delay still persists and Analytics events for function is still in beta. How are we supposed to test our functions' while this type of delay?

Comment: @jessimir did you solve this problem? I'm in the same case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The problem in my case was in the [data privacy settings](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6383877)  for my firebase project.
You must activate the "Sharing Analytics data with Firebase features" option, otherwise cloud function trigger from Google Analytics event will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and checked all the settings mentioned by @yasyd , but none of those helped.
2 hours after I got my event log trigger deployed and turned on the conversion event, my cloud function started to work and got fired when an event was logged, so it just need some time.
I guess they should mention this delay in the Firebase Functions documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Issue I faced was it was a web app I was trying to send the conversion analytics from, in order to trigger cloud function. But doc says it is not supported.

`Only iOS and Android events marked as conversion events are currently supported by Cloud Functions; Web conversion events are not currently available. You can specify which events are conversion events in the Events tab of the Firebase console Analytics pane.`